# How to override a Django url path that is provided by a library?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm currently building out an authentication server using Django, `djangorestframework`, and `django-rest-auth`. My problem is actually pretty simple I think, but I haven't really been able to find any resources on it.

Here's my issue, in `django-rest-auth` there is a specific url to change a user's password, which is `/rest-auth/password/reset/`. I'd like the url to instead be `/auth/password/change/`, but don't want to edit the library code to do so.

The issue is that as of now, in my url.py file, I have the rest-auth urls imported as such:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('rest_auth.urls')),
]
```

So it just imports the urls as written in the library. How can I change the specific url to what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a url like this

```
path('/auth/password/change/', your_view)
```

`your_view` will be same as view of `/rest-auth/password/reset/` which is `PasswordResetView`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, in hindsight I should have known to try it, haha.